# can't pull docker tomcat image

Tags: docker, tomcat, docker-image

after login in docker also cant pull image and see this error:

> unauthorized: authentication required

```
$ docker pull tomcat:latest
latest: Pulling from library/tomcat
57df1a1f1ad8: Pull complete
71e126169501: Pull complete
1af28a55c3f3: Pull complete
03f1c9932170: Downloading  40.37MB/51.83MB
881ad7aafb13: Download complete
9c0ffd4062f3: Download complete
bd62e479351a: Downloading  29.71MB/196.2MB
48ee8bc64dbc: Downloading
6daad3485ea7: Waiting
bc07a0199230: Waiting
unauthorized: authentication required
```

Comment: After login to docker are you getting the message `Login Succeeded`?

Comment: yes @JulianoCosta

`Authenticating with existing credentials...
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.                                                                               json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-st                                                                               ore

Login Succeeded`

Comment: Are you able to try to pull the image from a different network? Maybe without a VPN, or with a VPN if you are not using one.

Comment: THX @JulianoCosta I tested on other machine with same network configuration and pull successfully finished but on my server i can't pull it.